# Building a webscraper of realtor information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I created the first scraper designed to only read the first page of information of realtor.com under phoenix realtors. I can read and extract the 20 realtors on page 1 with absolutely no problems.

However I wanted to spice it up and try and read multiple pages of information I am not good at writing loops so i turned to the internet and i keep getting stuck specifically i am getting this error:

"line 42, in <module agent_number = number.text.strip() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'".

I was getting a few other errors along the way that i was trying to fix.

```
Below is the code i wrote trying to add a loop so i can read the first 30 pages of realtor information however i am getting a little stuck. If any of you geniuses can see what i am doing wrong it would be a great help. Here is the new code which is giving me the error stated above:

import requests
from requests import get
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-2'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#read page 
page_html = uClient.read()
#close page
uClient.close()

pages = np.arange(1, 30, 1)

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-2" + str(page) + "&ref_=adv_nxt", headers=headers)


#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

sleep(randint(2,10))

#finds all realtors on page 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"agent-list-card clearfix"})

for container in containers:
    name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
    agent_name = name.text.strip()

    number = container.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
    agent_number = number.text.strip()


print("name: " + agent_name)
print("number: " + agent_number)
```

Comment: Look at the previous line. Your `container.find()` function failed to find anything and returned `None`, which became the value of `number`. `None` doesn't have any methods or attributes, so there's your error.

Comment: Yes however i used that same code in my other scaper without trying to loop and it grabs the first page of information from realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az perfectly now when i use the starting point as realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-2 it isn't returing the information found on page.

Comment: Okay Matt sorry i found the issue i didnt have a rule written in to skip over content that didnt have information so it would break the loop thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webscraper won't loop from page 2 to page 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144929/webscraper-wont-loop-from-page-2-to-page-5)