# Webscraper won't loop from page 2 to page 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am using https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-2 as my starting point. I want to go from page 2 to page 5 and each page in-between while collecting names and numbers. I am collecting information on page 2 perfectly however I can not get it to go to the next page without having to plug in a new url. I am trying to set up a loop to do this automatically however after coding what I thought would be a loop im just getting the information only on page 2 (the starting point) before the scraper stops.
I am new too loops and have tried multiple ways but can get none to work.

Below is the complete code for now.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange
import pandas as pd 

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5)'
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                          'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),
                          'referer': 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-2'}

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-2'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#read page 
page_html = uClient.read()
#close page
uClient.close()

pages = np.arange(2, 3, 1)

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-" , headers=headers)

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#finds all realtors on page 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"agent-list-card clearfix"})

#creating csv file 
filename = "phoenix.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "agent_name, agent_number\n"
f.write(headers)

#controlling scrape speed 


for container in containers:

    try:
        name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
        agent_name = name.a.text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        print("-")

    try:
        number = container.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
        agent_number = number.text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        print("-")
    except NameError:
        print("-")

    try:
        print("name: " + agent_name)
        print("number: " + agent_number)
    except NameError:
        print("-")

    try:
        f.write(agent_name + "," + agent_number + "\n")
    except NameError:
        print("-")

f.close()
```

Comment: also i realize i set np.arange to stop at page 3 that was for testing purposes.

Comment: `requests.get("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-"`  Did you intend to fill in a page number after the `pg-`?

Comment: I tried with and without. I was under the impression that this is the link that doesn't change from page to page so the loop would add the next number in line. Still not exactly sure how the loops work. However I am trying to go from pg-2 followed by pg-3,then pg-4 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you need, but here's a working (and simplified) code based on your example that scrapes the first five pages.

If you take a close look, I'm using a `for loop` to "move" thru the pages by appending the page number to the url. Then, I get the HTML, parse it for agent div, grab name and number (if `None` then I add `N/A`) and finally dump the list to a `csv` file.

EDIT: To match the comments, I've added a city `Pheonix` and a `wait_for` feature that stops the script for any time between 1 to 10 seconds, adjustable.

```
import csv
import random
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


realtor_data = []

for page in range(1, 6):
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")
    url = f"https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-{page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    for agent_card in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "agent-list-card clearfix"}):
        name = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-name text-bold"}).find("a")
        number = agent_card.find("div", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
        realtor_data.append(
            [
                name.getText().strip(),
                number.getText().strip() if number is not None else "N/A",
                "Pheonix",
             ],
        )
    wait_for = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(f"Sleeping for {wait_for} seconds...")
    time.sleep(wait_for)

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["NAME:", "PHONE NUMBER:"])
    w.writerows(realtor_data)
```

Output:

A `.csv` file with realtor's name and phone number.

```
NAME:                     PHONE NUMBER:    CITY:
------------------------  ---------------  -------
Shawn Rogers              (480) 313-7031   Pheonix
The Jason Mitchell Group  (480) 470-1993   Pheonix
Kyle Caldwell             (602) 390-2245   Pheonix
THE VALENTINE GROUP       N/A              Pheonix
Nancy Wolfe               (602) 418-1010   Pheonix
Rhonda DuBois             (623) 418-2970   Pheonix
Sabrina Hurley            (602) 410-1985   Pheonix
Bryan Adams               (480) 375-1292   Pheonix
DeAnn Fry                 (623) 748-3818   Pheonix
Esther P Goh              (480) 703-3836   Pheonix
...
```

Comment: You're a god amongst men ! I am very beginner at this as im sure you can tell. I have a follow up question. Do i have to worry about getting anysort of ban if I run through say 30 pages of data? I know sleep(randint(10,30)) not sure if this is needed or not however! But seriously thank you so fricken much.

Comment: Also one more question sorry, if i wanted to pre-fill another column in the csv file with the city without having to take it from the website is this possible. I.E. Name - Number - City "city would  be prefilled saying phoenix" for every colum. Sorry if that doesn;t make sense i am not on much sleep aha.

Comment: Yes, scraping too fast too many pages might get you a ban, though a temporary one, at first. Adding a static city is easy. Just and `"Pheonix"` after the line with `number.getText()`.

Comment: Thanks so much seriously ! Does it matter where in the code i add the sleep randint?

Comment: Also I am pretty slow and having a hard time getting the phoenix to prefill if you could drop how that might look, I know you explained but my brain is still slow as i am just learning all this!

Comment: @qwpr I've udpated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move between pages:

```
page_html = requests.get("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az//pg-"+ str(page), headers=headers)
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

Also you have mistake with variable name it should be page_html

Comment: This is the error after changing the line of code: " TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int32") to str " Also not sure which line you are reffering to for the variable name page_html..

Comment: Thanks page_html seemed to do something here now i am getting this error. No idea where to even start with this one lol :  File "pageloop.py", line 33, in <module>
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\Cooper\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 307, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: Please accept this answer and open a new one if you need